# How are the off-world colonies reached in Blade Runner?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner, do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep

From references only from the 1982 *Blade Runner* movie and *Do Androids Dream Of Electric Sheep?* is there any indication how the science works to reach the "off-world colonies"? Especially for colonies that aren't in the solar system?

(Eg Wormholes, Jump drives, Generation ships...)

Comment: In the 1982 movie, there are ads promoting life off-world (that the ads' targeted audience can enjoy); boarding a generational ship to get there wouldn't make much sense. Also, the replicants who found their way back to Earth had only a few years to live; without relatively quick transport to Earth, the trip would have been pointless for them. Maybe generational ships exist(ed) in the movie's universe, but there must also have been much faster ways to get around.

Comment: @AnthonyX You've reminded me that in the book there's a TV interview of an immigrant to Mars asking her how she contrasted her life compared with before she emigrated, but that's already currently reachable.

Comment: Do you hold that the [Bladerunner and Alien](http://www.denofgeek.com/us/movies/alien/265927/are-alien-blade-runner-set-in-the-same-universe) universes [are the same](http://www.ign.com/articles/2017/11/08/how-are-blade-runner-and-alien-connected) or not?

Comment: Why only the book & 1982 movie? Seems like a burdensome restriction.

Comment: For purposes of this question Bladerunner != Alien universe, although good point :)

Comment: Why only the book and the movie? To limit contradictory sources; the book and movie are different enough. Plus I am using this information for a game based only these two aspects rather than any other parts.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It seems that film and book might have different interpretations of this.

I really don't remember the book that well, so what do we know about the film interpretation related to off-world travel and distances?

<sub>All quotes taken from the *Blade Runner* script.</sub>

### Travel between Earth and at least one colony takes comparatively little time

> *Bryant*: There was an escape from the off-world colonies **two weeks ago**. Six replicants, three male, three female. They slaughtered twenty-three people and jumped a shuttle. An aerial patrol spotted the ship off the coast. No crew, no sight of them. **Three nights ago** they tried to break into Tyrell Corporation.

So, at most the travel from colony to Earth took 11 days; more likely less, since we would presume replicants had to take some time to orient themselves.

If we are talking sub-light speeds of anything compared to our current capabilities, ***this wouldn't work*** for even the planet that is closest to Earth at some time: Venus -- Universe Today [lists the fastest journey](https://www.universetoday.com/36288/how-long-does-it-take-to-get-to-venus/) so far to have taken 110 days.

So, we are talking either at least 10x+ faster sub-light speeds than currently possible, or generation ships or some sort of hyperjumps.

### Replicants (at least the Nexus 6 model) have a 4 year life span

> *Bryant*: The designers reckoned that after a few years they might develop their own emotional responses. You know, hate, love, fear, anger, envy. So they built in a fail-safe device.
>
> *Deckard*: Which is what?
>
> *Bryant*:  **Four year life span.**

This one means that ***these are not generation ships***, unless we're talking cryogenic freezing or something similar, or replicants would not arrive at colonies at all. Also, you don't need a generation ship for a travel of 11 days either.

### Tannhäuser Gate

This part is subject to quite some interpretation, however, there are some things which seem logical to me.

As noted in one of the previous answers, Roy Batty's "Tears in the rain" monologue includes references to events he himself witnessed apparently near Orion. Orion nebula is approximately 1,344 *light-years* [distance from Earth](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Orion_Nebula). Alternatively, he could be talking about Orion *constellation*, which would also make sense, as Orion is a hunter in Greek mythology and therefore his constellation would naturally have a "shoulder". It doesn't change the underlying idea, however, since even the closest star in the Orion constellation is more than [200 light-years away](https://www.space.com/3380-constellations.html).

If we accept Roy's monologue that way, it means that during his near 4 years of life he has managed to get somewhere near the Orion nebula/constellation. It is possible that he was posted there and later on got back near Earth, however, at any rate the implication would be that **there *is* some sort of FTL travel in BR universe, at least in the film version**.

As I mentioned in a comment, I have always assumed that the Tannhäuser Gate mentioned by Roy in the same monologue is some sort of warp gate or similar. This view is apparently shared by other viewers up to the point that it is mentioned in [BR fandom wiki entry](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Tannhauser_Gate).

**As a coherent alternative**, if we assume Roy was speaking of seeing attack ships that appeared to be "off the shoulder of Orion", it might mean that he simply saw the ship on the *background* of Orion nebula or constellation. I am not aware how good would either look from any Solar system planet, but assuming Orion nebula could look impressive from any of them, we could assume that off-world colonies are (at closest), for example, just Mars and/or Venus, and **the 11-day travel is simply ~10-20x faster rockets**.

This would tie in better with the book, which speaks of colony on Mars etc, as written in another answer. And we presume script writers read the book after all. In that case you could argue that book talks about sub-light travel speeds in all cases. The journey to Proxima Centauri, which is mentioned in the book as described in @Nicola Talbot's answer and which @anaximander calculated as done at around 0.1-0.2c would fit as well, leaving slower speeds for inner system travels (probably because of not enough space/time for acceleration to 0.1c between Earth and Solar system planets).

Comment: More on the Tannhauser gate: http://bladerunner.wikia.com/wiki/Tannhauser_Gate

Comment: FTL is not required, due to time dilation. On a ship traveling at 0.99999993c, you’d travel 1344 light years in 6 months, as measured on the ship.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Quite right. However, how would you account for the 10 day travel from colony to Earth as perceived by *people on Earth*?

Comment: @Gnudiff: Right, but the Nexus lifespan is not a factor. That part is incorrect.

Comment: @DietrichEpp one could argue that 6 months out of 4 years is considerable waste - more than 12%, but you're right in that it would be far from impossible. I'll amend the answer.

Comment: Sadly, I think assuming that the script-writers actually read the book might not always be wise.

Comment: 11 days could also be just the difference between a 1 *c* signal sent to Earth and their ship. Accelerating to a near-*c* velocities that fast though would probably turn most things into a smear.

Comment: I always understood it as Roy describing what he *saw*, not just "what happened": "I've seen things you people wouldn't believe. Attack ships on fire off the shoulder of Orion. I watched C-beams glitter in the dark near the Tannhäuser Gate." In other words, the ships weren't *near* the Orion constellation; they were just off Orion's shoulder *from Roy's perspective*. For someone who's not got even four years of memories, such a view would be absolutely mind-blowing; He's talking about how amazing it was to see, not just about knowing that it happened.

Comment: If the Tannhauser gate isn't a warp gate, then what is it?  I can't think of any other reason one would have a "gate" in space.  Ultimately, like much of Blade Runner, this information lies somewhere on a spectrum between "mysterious" and "plot hole".

Comment: @MaxWilliams yes, it seems to be a strong feeling that it is something like that. In terms of movie it fits well. The only thing is it was invented on spot by Rutger Hauer, so it only makes sense for the movie. Hence my note on different interpretations. It seems PKD might have been thinking Solar system colonies, vs movie thinking more "global".

Comment: @Gnudiff I think you're right, since colonies on the moon and other solar system planets feature heavily in PKD's other works.  It is funny that one of the actors contributed so much to the off-screen universe of BR with that one line.

Comment: There might be off world colonies much closer than Venus - factories or asteroid mining/reprocessing in Earth orbit or on the Moon.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as I'm more familiar with the film than the book (having watched it far too many times) and you've extrapolated from key points in the film useful information that can determine what type and aspects of technology CAN be available from the times and topics. Thanks!

Comment: @errantlinguist A great point.

Answer (score 28):

The only manned space vessel that I can find in the novel is in some dialogue (bold added):

> ‘The issue is not the legality of the bone marrow analysis,’ Eldon
>   Rosen said huskily. ‘The issue is that your empathy delineation test
>   failed in response to my niece. I can explain why she scored as an
>   android might. **Rachael grew up aboard *Salader 3*. She was born on it; she
>   spent fourteen of her eighteen years living off its tape library and
>   what the nine other crew members, all adults, knew about Earth. Then,
>   as you know, the ship turned back a sixth of the way to Proxima.
>   Otherwise Rachael would never have seen Earth — anyhow not until her
>   later life.**’
>
> *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?* Chapter 5.

So it seems that ships were used. Not quite generational if Rachael (had she genuinely been on the *Salader 3*) could have reached Proxima and then returned to Earth later in life, but the journey obviously takes years.

The only other space vessel that's mentioned is an autorocket, which appears to be unmanned and is used by smugglers (bold added):

> ‘It’s worthless, here, because here on Earth the craze never caught
>   on. Anyhow there’s plenty here, in the libraries; that’s where we get
>   all of ours — stolen from libraries here on Earth and **shot by
>   autorocket to Mars.** You’re out at night bumbling across the open
>   space, and all of a sudden you see a flare, and there’s a rocket,
>   cracked open, with old pre-colonial fiction magazines spilling out
>   everywhere. A fortune. But of course you read them before you sell
>   them.’ She warmed to her topic. ‘Of all —’
>
> *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?* Chapter 13.

Other references to space travel are vague, just ‘the ship’ without any technical details.

I think [@ruakh's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186119/how-are-the-off-world-colonies-reached-in-blade-runner/186122#comment505510_186122) is correct:

> but if this was a ten-person ship to travel 4.3 light-years then it's
>   probably not representative of how most people travel. (Perhaps
>   Saladar 3 was supposed to install something there that would enable
>   FTL travel?)

The first quote above about the *Salader 3* bound for Proxima (presumably the system around [Proxima Centauri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxima_Centauri), the closest star to us outside our solar system), is the only mention of a location outside of our solar system, so it could well be that the *Salader 3*'s trip was the first attempt to leave the solar system (which makes its failure memorable). The only off-world colony that's actually mentioned is Mars: Roy Baty, Pris etc are from Mars, and there's a TV interview with a woman who emigrated to Mars:

> ‘Let’s hear from Mrs Maggie Klugman,’ the TV announcer suggested to
>   John Isadore, who wanted only to know the time. ‘A recent immigrant to
>   Mars, Mrs Klugman in a[n] interview taped live in New New York had
>   this to say. Mrs Klugman, how would you contrast your life back on
>   contaminated Earth with your new life here in a world rich with every
>   imaginable possibility?’ A pause, and then a tired, dry, middle-aged,
>   female voice said, ‘I think what I and my family of three noticed most
>   was the dignity.’ ‘The dignity, Mrs Klugman?’ the announcer asker.
>   ‘Yes,’ Mrs Klugman, now of New New York, Mars, said. ‘It's a hard
>   thing to explain. Having a servant you can depend on in these troubled
>   times... I find it reassuring.’
>
> ‘Back on Earth, Mrs Klugman, in the old days, did you also worry about
>   finding yourself classified, ahem, as a special?’
>
> ‘Oh, my husband and myself worried ourselves nearly to death. Of
>   course, once we emigrated that worry vanished, fortunately forever.’
>
> *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?* Chapter 2.

If Mars is the only off-world colony at the time when the story is set (with Proxima the next target for exploration) then the journey is [feasible with our modern real-life technology](https://www.nasa.gov/content/journey-to-mars-overview).

Just in case the comments disappear, I'm copying [@anaximander's calculations](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186119/how-are-the-off-world-colonies-reached-in-blade-runner/186122?noredirect=1#comment505628_186122) here:

> If *Salader 3* flew one-sixth of the 4.3ly to Proxima, turned round, and
>   flew back, and that took 14 years, then that averages out at
>   approximately 0.1c (disregarding time dilation). Assuming a roughly
>   straight-line brachistochrone trajectory, under acceleration at all
>   times, then that's somewhere around 0.14*g* acceleration to 0.2c after
>   3.5 years, then 3.5 years to slow down and "stop", 3.5 years to get back to 0.2c heading Earthward, and 3.5 years to slow down and stop
>   back at Earth. That's all pretty approximate, but as a ballpark it's
>   all fairly reasonable by scifi standards.

Rosen is lying about Rachael but assuming he's basing her backstory on a girl who actually was born on the *Salader 3*, then that provides realistic upper and lower bounds, depending on whether she was born at the start of the journey or just before it turned back.

Comment: +1, but if this was a ten-person ship to travel 4.3 light-years then it's probably not representative of how most people travel. (Perhaps *Saladar 3* was supposed to install something there that would enable FTL travel?)

Comment: Isn't this presuming Rosen is telling the truth...

Comment: @wcullen He is lying about Rachael being human, but he wouldn't say "as you know" to a bounty hunter and then fabricate a story about a non-existent vessel. The *Salader 3* must've existed and been in the news (presumably for having turned back to Earth) otherwise Deckard would've queried it.

Comment: @ruakh Could be. I hadn't thought of that. I'll have another look to see if I can find anything else.

Comment: @Nicola Talbot I meant that she may not have been on the Salander 3, not that the ship didn't exist (sorry for any confusion). It is possible that her being on the ship is fabricated especially seeing as she's a replicant (although I'm not sure if this is pre or post replicant's being outlawed; or, even if they were, if this would have included being on the Salander 3).

Comment: @wcullen Oh, okay. I got the impression that she wasn't on the *Salander 3*, and Rosen was just using a real-life (in-universe) ship to provide a back story for his attempt to prove that Rachael is human (but it's a while since I read the book).

Comment: If *Salader 3* flew one-sixth of the 4.3ly to Proxima, turned round, and flew back, and that took 14 years, then that averages out at approximately 0.1c (disregarding time dilation). Assuming a roughly straight-line brachistochrone trajectory, under acceleration at all times, then that's somewhere around 0.14*g* acceleration to 0.2c after 3.5 years, then 3.5 years to slow down and "stop", 3.5 years to get back to 0.2c heading Earthward, and 3.5 years to slow down and stop back at Earth. That's all pretty approximate, but as a ballpark it's all fairly reasonable by scifi standards.

Comment: @anaximander It's occurred to me that there's no reference as to when Rachael (hypothetically) was born on the ship. She spent 14 years on it (according to Rosen), which includes the journey back, but she might've been born, say, half-way through the outward journey. If she had a chance of returning to Earth later in life, then it wouldn't have been too close to the turning point, but it might not have been soon after departure. (Although Rosen's lying about her being on the ship, he's intelligent enough to ensure the numbers make sense.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot That's true, but assuming she was born sometime before the ship set off gives us the shortest possible duration for the voyage, and thus the highest possible value for the ship's speed and acceleration. If she was born en route, that just means the ship is slower than my estimation, which just makes it even more reasonable from a scientific-accuracy point of view.

Comment: @anaximander Yes, that's true. There are other possibilities as well, such as the return voyage taking longer (perhaps the reason for returning was due to a problem with the engines), but as you say it provides upper and lower bounds.

Comment: If I could accept two answers I'd accept this answer as well; I'm not as familiar with the book (read twice vs. watched the film dozens of times) however you've done a great breakdown of info from the book source that is very interesting indeed. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolaTalbot, the book was written in 1968, so the ship was almost certainly launched after that. I read that the early prints of the book take place in 1992 (the one I read was set in the more realistic setting of January 2021). That means the ship couldn't have been flying more than 24 years.

Answer (score 8):

I disagree with the source used in [wcullen's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/186120/98028) saying:

> the "central issues [are] left un- or under-explained" including, "Where are the 'off world colonies'?"

Indeed, Mars is mentioned during chapter 2 of *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?*:

> "Let's hear from Mrs. Maggie Klugman," the TV announcer suggested to John Isidore, who  wanted only to know the time. "A recent **immigrant to Mars**, Mrs. Klugman in an interview taped live in New New York had this to say.

As for the jumpships/wormholes etc, there might be a *slight* indication during [Batty's monologue](https://youtu.be/NoAzpa1x7jU?t=1m50s) at the end of *Blade Runner*:

> Attack ships on fire off the shoulder of Orion.

So we have attack ships. Why not travel ships as well? Especially considering that Mars isn't *that* far, for a SF book at least.

Comment: I don't see the mention of Mars on a TV show...can you find that..?

I am not suggesting there aren't ships or that they could travel beyond the solar system, only that there isn't mention of it specifically.

There is space travel, for sure; but, where and how is left open.

This is why I think Bukatman's comment about some things being unexplained and others being under-explained is accurate to both the film and the novel.

Comment: @wcullen edited just now. And there's the Proxima thing Nicola Talbot quoted.

Comment: RE: Mars--you're correct. Luba, after she admits to being a replicant, says she's from Mars, too. Mars is mentioned quite a few times--my bad :-)

Comment: @wcullen no problem :)

Answer (score 6):

There's no indication of how the ships work in either the novel or the film (any iteration).

It shouldn't really be a surprise given that the workings of technology are not the focus of the story at all (e.g. there's little but cursory discussion of how the VK machine actually works or, in the novel, how the genetic disintegration occurs); Rather, how do some technologies challenge and hold a mirror to the question 'what is it to be human'.

Given PKD's skill as a SF writer and thinker, any discussions of details would be a distraction--IMO.

I also don't know of any mention that the off-world colonies are/are not beyond our solar system.

One of the best things about BR/DADOES is that, like any good SciFi, the "central issues [are] left un- or under-explained" (S. Bukatman, *Blade Runner*, p. 17)--including, "Where are the 'off world colonies'?" (*ibid*).

Comment: *Given PKD's skill as a SF writer and thinker, any discussions of details would be a distraction--IMO.*  I agree completely.  Good sci fi makes the reader / viewer ask, "I wonder how this works".  The same reader / viewer is often disappointed by the author's answer --- which is why the author shouldn't give one.  My favourite examples are the Star Wars prequel films.  Fans wondered intensely about Anakin's transformation to Vader, the mysterious "Clone Wars", etc. It would have been far better not to be exposed to these answers.

Comment: As @Nicola Talbot notes, the ship would be at least generational given that Rosen states that Rachel "spent fourteen of her eighteen years" and that the Salander 3 turned back while one sixth of the way to its destination (so it was expected to take approx. 84 years to get there which is technically about 3-and-a-bit generations where 25 years tends to equal a generation). Rosen could be lying about Rachel being on the ship, but true or not, likely the time frame regarding the trip and the ship are accurate.

Comment: @wcullen: If *Saladar 3* spent 14 years in space, then it took it only 7 years to get one-sixth of the way to Proxima Centauri, so the whole one-way trip would have be 42 years. (Still a very long time, to be sure.)

Comment: @ruakh Only Replicants can done do math good like that :-P

Answer (score 0):

The only comment I will make is that if you look at an illustration of the Orion constellation then you will see that the position of the shoulder of Orion is occupied by Betelguese.  Betelguese is a Red Giant star about 430 light years from the Solar System. The Tannhauser gate is a warp station in the vicinity of Betelguese. C beams are faster than light beams that push and pull spacecraft through the warp. In a deleted scene of the film Soldier, the battle of and the gate itself was pictured. To travel 430 light years in ten days means that you must travel at a speed of around 43 light years per day. So thats 43 x 365 light years in a year. That's a speed of about 16000 C.

Comment: I believe you have an answer to the question here but at the moment what you’ve written is really more of a comment on the question. As this is a question and answer site not a discussion forum answers should answer the question only. Could you [edit] this to focus more on answering the question? You also may want to take the [tour] and read [answer] to learn a little more about how the site works.